# PHP: exchange all keys with their associated values in an array and preserving even if value has several indentical occurrences

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP we do have function [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) for exchanging all keys with their associated values in an array, however I am looking for a the solution as follows with the help of php functions

**INPUT**

```
array(
    "a" => 1, 
    "b" => 1, 
    "c" => 2
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(
        1 => array("a", "b"), 
        2 => "c"
);
```

Comment: I think is 2=>array('c')

Comment: You will not get this done using standard php function. You will need to write own loop to do this.

Comment: @BogdanBurim, yes I do know without loop this is not possible and even I am doing the same in my code, but still as PHP array functions are so powerful, can't we do this with them at all or is it impossible?

Comment: @SukhjinderSingh I do not see matching php function for this task

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a php function for it, so you'll have to write your own. If you really want a mixture of nested arrays and values the way to go would be:

```
function my_array_flip($arr)
{
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($v, $new_arr))
        {
            if (is_array($new_arr[$v]))
            {
                $new_arr[] = $k;
            }
            else
            {
                $new_arr[$v] = array($new_arr[$v]);
                $new_arr[$v][] = $k;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $new_arr[$v] = $k;
        }
    }

    return $new_arr;
}
```

For your array this will return:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = array(
    "a" => 1, 
    "b" => 1, 
    "c" => 2
);

foreach ($source as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$value][] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think exists a function for that but you can achieve it with some code:

```
$input = [
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 1,
    "c" => 2,
];

$grouped = [];
foreach ($input as $key => $group) {
    $grouped[$group][] = $key;
}
```

Result:

```
var_dump($grouped);

array(2) {
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "a"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Sets always array as values because I guess this will simplify things when you'll use the result in your code.